# All Picklist values is not showing up on force.com site? (All values are available for the record type)

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am using picklist in force.com site but for some reason all values of picklist are not showing up on the force.com site (few of them are already displaying). I have also enabled all values for this record type. In fact this values of picklist are already seen in inside salesforce but not on the force.com site.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your Salesforce as the step below:

- maybe you can check your field's `Field-Level Security` first.
- If you think it's correct. Then check the user's (that you used for login) `Profile` access of the Object or maybe fields.
- If you don't want to give the access for the `Profile`, then you can add `Sharing` access for the `Profile`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, But this is only for the force.com site(out side of salesforce : Site guest users profile). When I have tried to test it inside with proper login credential. it is working as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all CRUD permissions @JooKang

Comment: This answer could benefit from a more elaborate explanation